# Grub loader comes up instead of Ubuntu login screen

Tags: system-installation

Can someone please help me? I have installed ubuntu 100% etc but it boots me to the grub loader after installation. I have UEFI on with secure boot off, when I installed I clicked "Remove all and just install Ubuntu" I'm not that technical of a person so I honestly don't know a lot of terms you may ask me. Most of the commands in the grub loader don't work, could this be just a bad installation?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Have you tried recovery mode from grub menu. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had [a problem](https://superuser.com/q/1200473/352691), where I couldn't load Ubuntu.

The solution was to **boot from [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)** from [Rod Smith](https://superuser.com/users/171594/rod-smith) and **copy** a `.efi`-file named `grubx64.efi` from the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`-directory to the `/boot/efi/EFI/Boot`-directory and rename it to `bootx64.efi`.

If this is not the solution, you may still be able to boot into ubuntu with the [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)!

Good luck!